# Companion constructor with no arguments: how-to?

Tags: scala

Scala 2.10:

```
class A(val x:Int=0) {
}

object A {
  def apply(x:Int): A = new A(x)   // works
  def apply(): A = new A()         // fails to compile
}

val b = A(123)   //   :-)
val a = A()      //   >-(
```

Solution?

Comment: This should work. What is the error message?

Comment: I tested and this WORKS. Please give more details about the error message you are getting and your scala version. 2.10.??

Comment: Hmm... Was copied verbatim out of eclipse. Seems to work today. Possibly scala-ide issue. Sorry guys - wasting your time.

Answer (score 2):

Even though your code should work (I suspect some implicit argument being at work here)
 you can simplify it by doing

```
object A {
  def apply(x: Int=0): A = New A(x)
}
```

while being shorter there's the drawback of being less DRY